# Cron expression like {0 0 0 ? * *#n} possible?

Tags: java, cron, cronexpression

I'm trying to make a cron expression for : "every day of the second week of each month"

With `org.quartz` and `org.joda`:

```
CronExpression c = new CronExpression("0 0 0 ? * *#2");
Date next = c.getNextValidTimeAfter(DateTime.now().toDate());
System.out.println(next);
```

It work fine (without ParseException) but don't give the good answer when asking the next date, it only give the next day.

With : `"0 0 0 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN#2"` it's like : `"0 0 0 ? * SUN#2"`

Does someone know an alternative (expression or library) or maybe it's just an impossible problem ^^.